# Uploading a calendar record to a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, calendar

I'm trying to create a form and part of it will allow the user to record a date.
I have found a snippet of code online that creates a calendar for the user to select their date but when I try to upload it to a database I get an empty query error.
Can anyone see where my error is? I'm trying to find tutorials about using calendars in html forms but there hasnt been anything worthwhile in my search if anyone could recommend one I'd be very grateful.

```
    <html>
<head>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="uploadCalendar.php" method="post">
  <strong>Date :</strong>  <input name="date" id="datepicker" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my code to upload it to the database. I'm only practising with the calendar element before I introduce multiple fields for uploading to the database

```
    $Date = $_POST['date'];

$query = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `calendar` (`date`) VALUES '$Date'");
if(!mysqli_query($mysqli, $query))
{
    echo "ERROR".mysqli_errno($query);
}
else
{
    header ("Location: calendar.php");
}
```

Comment: Thanks to both Jonathon and Lionel. Between both of your answers I have it working! I really appreciate the help and guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing the OO version of mysqli with the procedural.

```
$query = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `calendar` (`date`) VALUES '$Date'");
```

This will return TRUE if the query succeeded, therefore if it did succeed, the line after:

```
if(!mysqli_query($mysqli, $query))
```

is trying to execute another query, specifying TRUE as the query value. Also I think there's a syntax error in your query, i.e. I think there should be () around the values since you're specifying the columns. Try this:

```
$Date = $_POST['date'];

$ret = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `calendar` (`date`) VALUES ('" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($Date) . "');");
if(!$ret)
{
    echo "ERROR";
}
else
{
    header ("Location: calendar.php");
}
```

** Also, always make sure to escape user input before using it in database queries.

Comment: Thanks Jonathon, I'm still trying to get my head around php so thats where I am getting OO and procedural mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that field `date` has type DATE. DATE expects date values in format yyyy-mm-dd.

Your calendar however returns values with format mm/dd/yyyy

Thus you need either to change the format in the MySQL query:

```
$query = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `calendar` (`date`) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('$Date', '%m/%d/%Y'))");
```

Or change the date format returned from jQuery so that it fits the regular date format.